# Partition for a non partitioned ext4

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext4

I have a large almost full disk that was written with a ext4 FS but without being first partitioned. I need to use it with a Windows 7 machine (via ext2fs), but I also have a Linux machine available. Unfortunately the Windows Machine won't recognize the fs without a partition. Is it possible to wrap the existing ext4 fs in a partition on the Linux Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly if you have a very recent version of e2fsprogs.  You can use `e2image -arpO 1048576 /dev/sda` to move the whole filesystem 1 MiB to the right.  Before you move it you probably need to shave a little size ( at least 1 MiB ) off the end with `resize2fs` so that there will be room to move over.  After that you can use `parted` to create a partition table and a partition.

Note that this will take a long time and if you make a mistake or lose power during the move, you will lose all of your data, so you should make a backup first, and if you do that, then it is probably easier and faster to just format the drive and restore the backup.

Comment: If you use `gparted` you can perform the move and resize as a single operation: `gparted` then executes each of the necessary operations in sequence and verifies each stage.

Comment: @AFH, no, you can't since gparted only operates on disks that are already partitioned.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I've never used an unpartitioned disc, so I mistakenly assumed it would handle that as well.